# WKWebView ignores position: fixed of html navbar

Tags: html, css, ios, swift

I am developing a PWA with a basic chat-view. My problem is, while showing the chat view inside my iOS app `WKWebView` and opening my keyboard to enter some text, the view scrolls up and my actually fixed navigation-header of my PWA scrolls up as well. How can I pretend the nav-header scrolling up?

In my navigation header I am using this css:

```
.fixed-bottom, .fixed-top {   
    position: fixed;    
    right: 0;    
    left: 0;    
    z-index: 1030;    
}
```

When opening the view and scroll up and down without having the keyboard open, this issue does not appear. The navigation header is fixed how I specified in my CSS and does not move.

I've found out that this behavior does not appear if the app is build with a `WKWebView` that has only the half of the screen size.

```
@objc
func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
  guard let info = notification.userInfo else { return }
  guard let frameInfo = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
  let keyboardFrame = frameInfo.cgRectValue.height
  keyboardHeight = frameInfo.cgRectValue.height
  var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: webView.frame.height-keyboardHeight)
  webView.frame = rect
  webView.scrollView.frame = rect
}
```

I've tried to resize the `WKWebView` height. I substracted the keyboard height. Somehow that works, the header is fixed, but when i scrolled to the bottom, I can scroll more than it should be possible. That means I scroll down to the last message and then the input field scrolls up to the upper edge of the screen. I do not understand where this additional height comes from. I guess from the keyboard.

Could I fix this with my CSS or do I have to manipulate the `WKWebView`? In general I think, that the `WKWebView` can handle the keyboard but in this case I guess I have to prevent that the keyboard adds the additional space, am I right?

Comment: WKWebView is basically a `UIScrollView`. You can implement a `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and "fix" the scroll offset just after it was changed

Comment: Thank you @Olha, I am trying to do so but i am not sure what to change. I've tried these: `webView.scrollView.contentInset`, `webView.scrollView.contentOffset`, `webView.scrollView.contentSize` inside the `scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset` Method. Non of these worked. Could you please be more concrete?

Comment: Finally I needed to set the `contentInset.bottom` negative, to `-keyboardHight` to achieve not scrolling too deep.